# How to refresh/reload WooCommerce checkout page after adding a coupon code (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, refresh, reload

I need to reload the entire WooCommerce checkout page after adding a coupon code.
I tried the following code but it doesn't reload it.

The reason why I need this function:
Prices of the review table turns to defalut language prices after adding the coupon code.
When I refresh the page, it shows translated language prices, so I need to reload it.

Would you please let me know how to reload it?

**Added this code in a checkout page:**

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === '/?wc-ajax=apply_coupon') {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === '/?wc-ajax=apply_coupon') {
    jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
    }
});
```

**Order review table:**

```
<div class="ea-woo-checkout-order-review">
        <div class="ea-checkout-review-order-table">
            <ul class="ea-order-review-table">
                                    <li class="table-header">
                        <div class="table-col-1"></div>
                        <div class="table-col-2"></div>
                        <div class="table-col-3"></div>
                                   </li>
                
        <li class="table-row cart_item">
        <div class="table-col-1 product-thum-name">
        <div class="product-thumbnail">
        <img width="300" height="200" src="https://www.myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/LineOne_22-300x200.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy">                              </div>
        <div class="product-name">Template Type&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
                                <div class="table-col-2 product-quantity">1</div>
                                <div class="table-col-3 product-total"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>820,000</bdi></span></div>
        </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="ea-order-review-table-footer">
        <div class="footer-content">
        <div class="cart-subtotal">
            <div></div>
            <div><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>820,000</bdi></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-total">
        <div></div>
        <div><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>820,000</bdi></span></strong> </div>
        </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Apply coupon:**

```
<div class="woo-checkout-coupon">
            <div class="ea-coupon-icon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-percent"></i></div>
                            <div class="woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle">
    <div class="woocommerce-info">
        Have a coupon? <a href="#" class="showcoupon">Click here to enter your code</a> </div>
                </div>

                <form class="checkout_coupon woocommerce-form-coupon" method="post" style="">

                    <p>If you have a coupon code, please apply it below.</p>

                    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
                        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="Coupon code" id="coupon_code" value="">
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
                        <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="Apply Coupon">Apply Coupon</button>
                    </p>

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome at stack**overflow**.  Why add two separate queries (even with an identical condition) to *a checkout page*? The indentation of the HTML presented doesn't do much for me to follow closing tags - is there a `</div>` missing from **Apply coupon:**?

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
```

instead of

```
location.reload();
```

Alternative

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'woocommerce_custom_update_checkout', 50);

function woocommerce_custom_update_checkout()
{
  if (is_checkout()) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready($ => {

    $('input').on('change', () => {

      $('body').trigger('update_checkout');

    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Rajeev Singh: Thank you for your comment. I tried it based on your advice ( I updated the code aobve), but it still doesn't refrsh it after updating the coupon code. Would you please let me know other method if possible? Thank you.

Comment: open inspect (ctrl + shift + i), refresh the page and apply coupon code, then check js errors, I am sure few js errors coming when you applying coupon code, that's why block below/rest of js. otherwise jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout'); is common wp code

Comment: Hi Rajeev Singh: Thank you for your help. I check a console, and it shows no error. I need to refresh the entire checkout page after adding the coupon. Otherwise, it doesn't change to translated lanague prices... Sorry, I'm a newbie, very clumsy....

Comment: If possible share site URL and Test Coupon code

Comment: Hi Rajeev  : I was wondering if you could let me know any possible solution?

Comment: Hi, @namari, Sorry for the delay, I was out of the station last 3 days so I can't check. Now I am checking your checkout page it's working fine after applying the coupon "testcoupon".  it's working and reflecting discount price " 50,000" without refresh the page manually. you should also  trigger jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout'); after remove coupon. because when I removed the applied coupon we have to refresh the page again using the coupon code.

Comment: Hi Rajeev: Oh, I'm sorry to bother you and thank you for your help. The price ₩50,000 is not a coreect price as it's a default language price (it's not a translated price)... (When you refresh the page it shows ¥290 which is the correct price = translated price). Yeah, you are right, it also has to refresh the page on delecting coupon but it doesn't refresh the page with the code... I was wondering if you could help me? Thank you Rajeev

Answer (score 1):

In case someone who needs it
It's working with the following code:

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'applied_coupon_in_checkout removed_coupon_in_checkout', function () {
    location.reload();
} );
```